# Response.write doesn't display variable string

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, server

So, I'm learning node, tried to write simple server by my self. When it comes to write data to response, it doesn't work properly. I converted data to String, i tried to display data to the console and it had benn displayed normally, but when I pass it to response.write() nothing changes at my page. I created file called 'lorem' in poems/lorem directory, I write this path to my link in browser.
As you can see, I was writting some debugging stuff, but I deleted most of it.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs   = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var port = process.argv[2];

var readFileContent = (filePath) => 
{
    var readData = '';

    fs.readFile(path.normalize(process.cwd() + filePath), 'utf-8', (err, data) => 
    {
        let invalid = false;
        if(err || data === undefined)
        {
            invalid = true;
        }
        if(!invalid) readData = data;
        console.log(readData); // logs data from a file
    });

    return readData;
}

var serverHandler = (request, response) =>
{   
        let responseData = readFileContent(request.url);

        if(responseData != undefined)
        {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
            response.write(''+ responseData.toString()); // there is a problem: writes data only when I pass some exact string (e.g. 'LOREM')
        }
        else{
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write('Error occured');
        }
        response.end(responseData.toString());
    }


http.createServer(serverHandler).listen(+ port);


console.log('Server is lisntening on port ' + port);
```

There some console output for 'C:/folderpath/ node server.js 8080' cmd:

```
Server is lisntening on port 8080

lorem

lorem

lorem
```

Content of 'poems/lorem' file == 'lorem'

Comment: I also know that there is 'favicon.ico' request that ins't counted anyhow. I only created this file with no context('favicon.ico == ' '), so my code doesn't throw an error any time it requeststhis file. May it be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with asynchronicity.

Provide your file reading function with a callback, which returns the file content.

Like this:

```
var readFileContent = (filePath, callback) => 
{

    fs.readFile(path.normalize(process.cwd() + filePath), 'utf-8', (err, data) => 
    {
        let invalid = false;
        if(err || data === undefined)
        {
            invalid = true;
        }
        if(!invalid) readData = data;
        callback(readData)
    });
```

}

And in your server handler function do the following:

```
var serverHandler = (request, response) =>
{   
   readFileContent(request.url, (responseData) => {
      if(responseData != undefined) {
           response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
           response.write(''+ responseData.toString()); 
        }
       else {
          response.writeHead(404);
          response.write('Error occured');
       }
       response.end(responseData.toString());
    }); 
 }
```

Comment: that worked out. Thanks, gonna go through that code little bit deeper.